# How to automatically delete a virtual machine when it is turned off?

Tags: virtual-machine

I'm using `virt-install` to create a virtual machine which just needs to perform a single task. Once the task is performed, the machine is automatically turned off. Once it turns off, there is no need to keep either the virtual machine or its virtual disk.

I remember there were situations where virtual machines were unintentionally deleted once turned off. I don't remember, however, what made them disappear. `man virt-install` doesn't help either.

How do I create a machine in a way that it is automatically deleted once it's turned off?